# Building Data Structure out of JSON output

Tags: ruby, json, file, loops

Hi Im working on writing a script that pulls data out of a ticketing system. Once it pulls the data it analyze the content of it and if it the content match a specific criteria then it needs to build a data structure file that will be dump in the same server.

I was able to parse the data in JSON format, listed below is the content:

```
[{"id"=>10423,
  "type"=>"Ticket",
  "lastUpdated"=>"2014-11-04T10:58:47Z",
  "shortSubject"=>"FOO STATUS UPDATE",
  "shortDetail"=>"Reply to this message if all systems are functional..",
  "displayClient"=>"No Client",
  "updateFlagType"=>0,
  "prettyLastUpdated"=>"54 minutes ago",
  "latestNote"=>
   {"id"=>16850,
    "type"=>"TechNote",
    "mobileListText"=>"<b>t. trust: </b> All Systems are OK",
    "noteColor"=>"clear",
    "noteClass"=>"bubble right"}},

 {"id"=>10422,
  "type"=>"Ticket",
  "lastUpdated"=>"2014-11-04T10:54:07Z",
  "shortSubject"=>"FOO STATUS UPDATE",
  "shortDetail"=>"Reply to this message if all systems are functional..",
  "displayClient"=>"No Client",
  "updateFlagType"=>0,
  "prettyLastUpdated"=>"58 minutes ago",
  "latestNote"=>nil},

 {"id"=>10421,
  "type"=>"Ticket",
  "lastUpdated"=>"2014-11-04T10:53:17Z",
  "shortSubject"=>"FOO STATUS UPDATE",
  "shortDetail"=>"Reply to this message if all systems are functional..",
  "displayClient"=>"No Client",
  "updateFlagType"=>0,
  "prettyLastUpdated"=>"59 minutes ago",
  "latestNote"=>nil}]
```

In the data above you can see that each ticket has an id, lastupdate, short Subject, short Detail and lastest note the value of the latest note will be nill if no one reply to the ticket but if someone does reply then the value mobileListText will have something.

So what I need to do pretty much is once I get this data the script will look for the subject that complies with  "FOO STATUS UPDATE" if that value matches then looks for the content of the shortDetail matches "Reply to this message if all systems are functional.." and if this complies then looks for its latestNote, if latestNote is nill then it will create a log file specifiying date and time when it run, the id of the ticket with this state and a message saying, ticket has not being reply, but if the latest note has the value "mobileListText"=>"**t. trust:**  All Systems are OK", then creates the follwing data structure:

```
{"LastUpdate":1415130257,"Service":[{"time":"11-04-2014 10:58:47 GMT","region:":"","id":"","description":"All Systems are OK","service":""},{"time":"11-04-2014 10:54:07 GMT","region:":"","id":"","description":"All Systems are OK","service":""},{"time":"11-04-2014 10:53:17 GMT","region:":"","id":"","description":"All Systems are OK","service":""}]}
```

Im able to have part of this however, based on the data above, only one ticket has All Systems are OK, meaining that only one of the tickets has being reply, and it only should write something like this:

```
{"LastUpdate":1415130257,"Service":[{"time":"11-04-2014 10:58:47 GMT","region:":"","id":"","description":"All Systems are OK","service":""}]}
```

But Instead repeats this only ticket that has being replied serveral times.

this my code so far:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'json'
require 'net/http'
require 'highline/import'
require 'pp'
require 'logger'



@usersol='foo'
@passol= 'foo123'
@urlsol= "http://dev-webhelpdesk.foo.corp:8081/helpdesk/WebObjects/Helpdesk.woa/ra/Tickets?list=group&page=1&limit=#{@limit}&username=#{@usersol}&password=#{@passol}"
@limit = '25'
@log = @log= Logger.new( 'message_solar.log')






 def ticket_data                                              #looks for ticket data in solarwinds
    resp = Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse(@urlsol))
    url_output = resp.body
    JSON.parse(url_output)
  end

#CRONJOB THAT START ALL
#echo "Reply to this message if all systems are functional.." | mail -r noc@foo.com  -s "FOO STATUS UPDATE:" noc-team@FOO.com >> /dev/null
                                          # Looking for all the tickets  with the following content
                                          # ticket id, ticket subject and content
  def search_allok(allok)
    description = []
    allok.each do |systems|
      output1 = systems.has_key?'id'
      if output1
        systems.values_at('shortSubject').each do | subject |
         output2 = subject.match(%r(TRUST STATUS UPDATE))
         if output2
           latestnote = systems.values_at('latestNote')
           latestnote.each do |content|
            if content
             final = content.values_at('mobileListText')
             final_ok = final[0].sub!(/^\<b\>.*\<\/b\>\s/, "")
             systems_ok = final_ok.match(%r(All Systems are OK))
                if systems_ok
                  ids = systems['id']
                  notify = {"LastUpdate" => Time.now.to_i, "Service" => []}
                  allok.each do |lastup|
                    reference = lastup.has_key? 'id'
                    if reference
                      timeid = lastup.values_at('lastUpdated')
                      timeid.each do |lines|
                        final=lines.split(/[-, T, Z]/)
                        notify["Service"] << { "time" => "#{final[1]}-#{final[2]}-#{final[0]} #{final[3]} GMT", "region:" => "", "id" => "#{ids}", "description" => "#{systems_ok}" , "service" => ''}
                      end
                    end
                  end
                  File.open("notify.json", "w") do |fileformatted|
                    fileformatted.puts (JSON.dump(notify))
                  end
                 else
                  time = Time.now
                  @log.info("#{time} - Ticket ID #{systems['id']} has not being updated")
                end
            else
              @log.info("#{time} - Ticket ID #{systems['id']} has not being reply")
            end
           end
         end
       end
      end
    end
  end







                                    # If the content is there then it need to create
                                    # the data structure including the lastupdated                                                    
                                    # (time when it run the script), and the lastupdate for the ticket                                                                                  
                                    # and the description All Systems OK

#This method below I added to the one above, but I was thinking on doing it separate but I encouter issues passing the information needed from above to below

  def datastructure(format_file)            #creates JSON file lastupdated of each ticket in the queue
    notify = {"LastUpdate" => Time.now.to_i, "Service" => []}
     format_file.each do |lastup|
       reference = lastup.has_key? 'id'
       if reference
         timeid = lastup.values_at('lastUpdated')
         timeid.each do |lines|
          final=lines.split(/[-, T, Z]/)
            notify["Service"] << { "time" => "#{final[1]}-#{final[2]}-#{final[0]} #{final[3]} GMT", "region:" => "", "id" => "", "description" => region , "service" => ''}
         end
       end
    end
    File.open("notify.json", "w") do |fileformatted|
      fileformatted.puts (JSON.dump(notify))
    end
  end

#ticket_data
#datastructure(ticket_data)
search_allok(ticket_data)
```

Comment: Can you cut this down to a **minimal** example of what you want to achieve?

Comment: if you want to append to the file, you need to use `a` not `w`

Comment: What I want to achieve is this structure: {"LastUpdate":1415130257,"Service":[{"time":"11-04-2014 10:58:47 GMT","region:":"","id":"","description":"All Systems are OK","service":""},{"time":"11-04-2014 10:54:07 GMT","region:":"","id":"","description":"All Systems are OK","service":""},{"time":"11-04-2014 10:53:17 GMT","region:":"","id":"","description":"All Systems are OK","service":""}]}

Answer (score 0):

The code you've written is basically doing a roundabout version of what is achieved by using ruby's map and select methods. See this article: [Ruby Explained: Map, Select, and Other Enumerable Methods](http://www.eriktrautman.com/posts/ruby-explained-map-select-and-other-enumerable-methods)